# Filter List of Class by Property Value and List Of Value

Tags: vb.net, filtering

I have a Devexpress Gridcontrol bound to a custom class.

The class looks like this:

```
  Public Class AuditList
            Public CasualtyList As List(Of CasualtyRecords)
            Public MedsList As List(Of CasualtyRecords.Medications)

            Public Property FilterString As CriteriaOperator

            Public Sub New()
                CasualtyList = New List(Of CasualtyRecords)
                MedsList = New List(Of CasualtyRecords.Medications)
            End Sub

            Public Class CasualtyRecords
                Private _primary As New PS
                Public Property PrimarySurvey As PS
                    Get
                        Return _primary
                    End Get
                    Set(value As PS)
                        _primary = value
                    End Set
                End Property

                Public Sub New()
                    Vitals = New List(Of VitalRecords)
                End Sub
                Public Property Vitals As List(Of VitalRecords)
                Public Property Meds As List(Of Medications)

                ReadOnly Property MedCount As Integer
                    Get
                        Return Meds.Count
                    End Get
                End Property

                Property Id As Integer
                Property ClinicalImpression As String
                Property Disposal As String
                Property Age As Integer
                Property Gender As String

                Class PS
                    Public Property Airway As Integer
                    Public Property Breathing As Integer
                    Public Property Circulation As Integer
                    Public Property Rate As Integer
                 End Class

               Class Medications
                    Public Property MedName As String
               End Class
            End Class
        End Class
```

This is an example of a filter type I am trying to create:

> "[Gender] ='Male' AND [Medications].[MedName] = 'Paracetamol' AND [Age] >100"

Is this possible with the class constructed as shown, or perhaps do I need to implement some other interface?

I imagine that it would look something like this with LINQ

```
  Dim b As New CasualtyRecords
  b = a.CasualtyList.Where(Function(x) x.Meds.Any(Medications.Med = "Paracetamol") And x.Gender = "Male" And x.Age > 20)
```

Thanks

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do or ask.  `AuditList` contains a public field `CasualtyList` which is a `List(Of CasualtyRecords)`.  But `CasualtyRecords` inherits from `AuditList` which means each `AuditList.CasualtyList(n)` item will also have a `CasualtyList` collection. It all seems untenable.  Its also not clear what this has to do with the grid control.  Please read **[ask]** and take the **[tour]**

Comment: Im sorry if it is not clear. I think the `inherit` element is left over from a previous revision. The filter text is what is passed to the GridControl. Essentially what I am asking is, if it is possible to filter / select Objects from a List based on a 1/2 string/integer properties with the base class and then from a list of(Type) items in a sub Class. I have updated the code on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the required results using this LINQ query

```
Dim newrecords = a.CasualtyList.Where(
        Function(x) x.Meds.Any(
            Function(b) b.MedName = "Paracetamol") _
            And x.Gender = "Male" And x.Age > 20).ToList()
```